# How to send email from ssmtp with HTML

Tags: email, ssmtp

I want to send an HTML report that is piped from another command, eg: `mycommandthatprintshtml | mail someone@hostname.com` . When I do this currently, it prints all the html tags. Is there a way I can set the required headers to make it display in HTML formatted?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the email body, you also need to print the email headers:

```
echo "From: from@example.com\r\nDate: $(date)\r\nSubject: subject\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n$(mycommandthatprintshtml)" mail someone@example.com
```

Note that From, Date, Subject are mandatory. MIME-Version and Content-Type are there to help the recipient understand how the email is formatted.

Comment: Message-ID is mandatory as well, or does SSMTP add it if necessary?

Comment: The RFC 5322 says that the message-id should be present, but it's not mandatory. Most of the servers will add one for you if it isn't. I don't know if SSMTP adds one for you.

Comment: Any chance of an example with HTML message plus attachment(s)?

Comment: @RTF late comment, but likely possible using `multipart/mixed`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250189/182991

Comment: @Giel SSMTP adds message id when necessary on my servers. I know I'm a bit late, but maybe someone else will neeed that information.

Answer (score 0):

with ssmtp you can send a mail from a file and specify headers inside (similar to what Federik did)

> ssmtp -t  < mail.txt

mail.txt:

```
to: write.to@mail.com
bcc: hidden@mail.com
From: my.name@mail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text; charset=utf-8
Subject: Some subject

Dear Person,
....
```